# What's a biholomorphic map between ℂ and a contractible bounded, open subset?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I'm trying to think about complex analysis in terms of (1D) complex manifolds, and many things  started to make more sense when I could talk about the Riemann sphere $ℂP^1$ as a „first-class citizen“ of our study of holomorphic maps.

It's reasonable to assume that open subsets of $ℂ$ are in fact complex submanifolds (German Wikipedia claims that at least) – but I fail to see how to put a reasonable atlas on them: For local biholomorphicity to $ℂ$, I would need something like a biholomorphic map from $\{z\mid |z|<\epsilon\}$ to $ℂ$.
I first thought about a simple rescaling, but anything involving the absolute value is not holomorphic, so that can't work.

> So, if it exists, what is a biholomorphic map from $\{z\mid |z|<\epsilon\}$ to $ℂ$?
> If it does not exist, are there other contractible, bounded open subsets of $ℂ$ for which this works?

I have just found out about the riemann mapping theorem, but that requires a proper subset of ℂ so it sounds like it cannot be applied.

Comment: contractible implies simply connected. By the Riemann mapping theorem, up to biholomorphism, $\Bbb{C}$ and the unit disk are the only non-empty, simply-connected open subsets of $\Bbb{C}$ (also the disk and the plane are not biholomorphic because of Louiville's theorem).

Comment: Check instead up on Liouville’s theorem.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about Liouville's theorem! That should be enough info for an answer @Mindlack.

Comment: In that case, my misunderstanding seemed to stem from the fact that a _chart_ need not be a biholomorphism to $\mathbb C^n$, but only an open subset of it. I think in real differential geometry this distinction does not quite matter, because $\mathbb R^n$ is locally homeomorphic to itself. So my extrapolation from the real case was incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer. By Liouville’s theorem, $\mathbb{C}$ isn’t biholomorphic to any open disk of the complex plane. Instead, in complex geometry (in dimension $n$) the charts are just biholomorphisms to open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$, as you wrote it.